# SWIFT: use of undeclared type of "detailViewController"

Tags: uitableview, swift, types, undeclared-identifier

I have looked at every answer on the internet and yet it keeps giving the error. I know this might be a repeat but the solutions are not working for me.

- I have made detailViewController a public class
- I have added detailViewController.swift target membership as my test target.

  ```
  import UIKit

   class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   var items:[Item]=itemData

  @IBAction func cancelToDetailViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){

   }
      @IBAction func saveItemDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
  let DetailTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as DetailTableViewController;


   }
  ```

  Error says use of undeclared type of "detailViewController"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "detailViewController" you mean your "DetailTableViewController" class, the problem is entirely in your naming conventions. What you're doing is attempting to assign your source view controller to a variable (or constant, it doesn't matter) "DetailTableViewController" which is already the name of your class. This is not allowed.

You need to name the variable something else. The convention is to have classes start with a capital letter and instances with a lowercase letter, which you should adhere to because it will help keep this kind of thing from happening in the future.

That said, the following should work for you. Notice the only difference is that the "d" in the beginning of the variable is lowercase instead of uppercase.

```
@IBAction func saveItemDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let detailTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as DetailTableViewController
}
```